# Dynamic middleware in Redux

Tags: redux

I'm using Redux to write a NodeJS app. I'm interested in allowing users to dynamically load middleware by specifying it at runtime.

**How do I dynamically update the middleware of a running Redux application to add or remove middleware?**

Comment: How would you prefer to control which middleware are active?

Comment: I started working on a PoC that had a `middleware` array in the state, and it would run actions through the provided middleware in sequence. To answer your question though I'd prefer to use best practices, whatever that may be.

Comment: I don't think there is a best practice for this. Its not clear why you would dynamically load different middleware at runtime. Are you trying to differentiate development and production builds? Are you wanting to turn on or off middleware from while the application is running in production? SOme context would here in this case i think.

Comment: Basically you create a store with middlewares 'baked in', so I don't think there's a good way around. Sounds like you're going to do something quite strange, so more context maybe?

BTW, you could use your store state to differentiate middleware behaviour, maybe this would help?

Comment: I realize this is a stretch of the architecture; this is for a desktop app (Electron) that will allow the user to download and install plugins. I'd like to be able to immediately enable the plugins (load from disk and start handling actions) without requiring users to restart the app.

Answer (score 7):

Middleware is not some separate extension, it's part of what your store *is*. Swapping it at runtime could lead to inconsistencies. How do you reason about your actions if you don't know what middleware they'll be run through? (Keep in mind that middlewares don't have to operate synchronously.)

You could try a naive implementation like the following:

```
const middlewares = [];
const middlewareMiddleware = store => next => act => {
  const nextMiddleware = remaining => action => remaining.length
    ? remaining[0](store)(nextMiddleware(remaining.slice(1)))(action)
    : next(action);
  nextMiddleware(middlewares)(act);
};
// ... now add/remove middlewares to/from the array at runtime as you wish
```

but take note of the middleware contract, particularly the `next` argument. Each middleware receives a *"pass to the next middleware"* function as part of its construction. Even if you apply middlewares dynamically, you still need to tell them how to pass their result to the next middleware in line. Now you're faced with a loss-loss choice:

1. action will go through all of the middleware registered at the time it was dispatched (as shown above), even if it was removed or other middleware was added in the meantime, or
2. each time the action is passed on, it goes to the next currently registered middleware (implementation is a trivial excercise), so it's possible for an action to go through a combination of middlewares that were never registered together at a single point in time.

It might be a good idea to avoid these problems alltogether by sticking to static middleware.

Answer (score 6):

Use `redux-dynamic-middlewares`

https://github.com/pofigizm/redux-dynamic-middlewares

Comment: Thanks for creating and sharing this great package!

Answer (score -2):

Attempting to change middleware on-the-fly would violate the principle of 'pure' actions and reducer functions, because it introduces side-effects. The resulting app will be difficult to unit-test.

Off the top of my head, it might be possible to **create multiple stores** (one for each possible middleware configuration), and use a parent store to provide the state switch between them. You'd move the data between the sub-stores when switching. Caveat: I've not seen this done, and there might be good reasons for not doing it.

Comment: multiple stores is against redux principles as well.

Comment: `The resulting app will be difficult to unit-test` If unit testing is testing a code unit in isolation with application context how adding middle ware to store be difficult.